# How to recreate .pem file if I forgot to save it when created Key Pair in AWS EC2 using boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, key-pair

I did this:

```
try:
    ec2.get_all_key_pairs(keynames=[key_name])[0]
    print 'Key pair %s exist'%key_name
except ec2.ResponseError, e:
    if e.code == 'InvalidKeyPair.NotFound':
        print 'Creating key_pair %s'%key_name
        key = ec2.create_key_pair(key_name)
    else:
        raise
```

And as you can see, I created a key_pair, but forgot to save it =(
Than I launched instance and realized that I don't have .pem file on my computer, is there any way to recreate it?

Comment: No. just replace your instance. This is the cloud way.

Comment: Guy is right, can't be done.  Start over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- mount the root disk of this instance to some other (test) instance.
- go to *folder/home/ec2-user(or other)/.ssh* directory.
- you should have any private key file on your local system,
- then create/export openssh public key from that new private key file and replace the PublicKey file with *authorized_keys* (change permissions, ownerships, etc)
- unmount that old instance disk & then start the instance.
- now try to connect with new ppk file.

Have a nice luck..